# PHPExcel_Style_Fill infinite recursion

Tags: php, recursion, phpexcel

I use library `PHPExcel 1.7.9` to work with `Excel` files. First, I create a template, stylise and polish it. Then, to avoid style hardcoding, using the above mentioned library I open that template, change some values and save it as a new `.xlsx` file.

First, we fetch that style from cells.

```
$this->styles = array() ;
$this->styles['category'] = $sheet->getStyle("A4");
$this->styles['subcategory'] = $sheet->getStyle("A5");
```

Here is the recursive function, that displays categories and subcategories.

```
private function displayCategories($categories, &$row, $level = 0){
    $sheet = $this->content ;

    foreach($categories as $category){
        if ($category->hasChildren() || $category->hasItems()){ //Check if the row has changed.
            $sheet->getRowDimension($row)->setRowHeight(20);
            $sheet->mergeCells(Cell::NUMBER . $row . ":" . Cell::TOTAL . $row) ;

            $name = ($level == 0) ? strtoupper($category->name) : str_repeat(" ", $level*6) ."- {$category->name}" ;
            $sheet->setCellValue(Cell::NUMBER . $row, $name) ;
            $sheet->duplicateStyle((($level == 0) ?  $this->styles['category'] : $this->styles['subcategory']), Cell::NUMBER . $row);

            $row++ ;
            if ($category->hasChildren()){
                $this->displayCategories($category->children, $row, $level+1);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

---

**The problem**

If `$sheet->duplicateStyle()` is used, it will be impossible to save document because of infinite recursion.

> Maximum function nesting level of '200' reached, aborting! <- FATAL ERROR

The problem is in the next piece of code, inside `PHPExcel_Style_Fill` class, one object is referencing himself over and over.

```
public function getHashCode() { //class PHPExcel_Style_Fill
    if ($this->_isSupervisor) { 
        var_dump($this === $this->getSharedComponent()); //Always true 200 times
        return $this->getSharedComponent()->getHashCode();
    }
    return md5(
          $this->getFillType()
        . $this->getRotation()
        . $this->getStartColor()->getHashCode()
        . $this->getEndColor()->getHashCode()
        . __CLASS__
    );
}
```

Is any workaround to solve this? I would also accept any ideas on how to apply a complete style of one cell to another.

---

**Solution:**

As @MarkBaker said in comments, branch `develop` on GitHub really contains fixes to the bug.

Comment: Can't you just move `$sheet->duplicateStyle()` above `if ($category->hasChildren()`? Basically just have it on the foreach but not inside the conditional?

Comment: Do you mean I should move it out of `if` or make it first line under `if`?

Comment: Out of the if. Above it

Comment: Can you please try with the latest develop branch code from github, there's a couple of fixes to the duplicateStyle() method that have been implemented for the next release

Comment: @MarkBaker Is that branch called `develop 1.79`? I will take a look at it and inform you later.

Comment: No, it's the branch labelled `develop`

Comment: Alright, I will take a look.

Comment: If you are using xdebug, you can add an "xdebug.max_nesting_level=500" line to your php.ini file. Please do that and let me know.

Comment: @JigarChaudhary are you serious? I have 20 items in that array. Even that I set it to 50 000, the object will not stop referencing itself.

Comment: @JigarChaudhary - the test showing that $this == $this->getSharedComponent() proves it's an infinite case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT** I added a pull request with a fix: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/pull/251

This happens when you try to duplicate cell's style to the same cell; Take a look at this:

```
$phpe = new PHPExcel();
$sheet = $phpe->createSheet();

$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'hi there') ;
$sheet->setCellValue('A2', 'hi again') ;

$sheet->duplicateStyle($sheet->getStyle('A1'), 'A2');

$writer = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($phpe);
$writer->save('./test.xlsx');
```

It will work just fine. **BUT** if I add another line like this:

```
$sheet->duplicateStyle($sheet->getStyle('A1'), 'A1');
```

then bang, infinite recursion starts after calling the `save` method

To fix your code, you should modify this part:

```
$sheet->duplicateStyle((($level == 0) ?  $this->styles['category'] : $this->styles['subcategory']), Cell::NUMBER . $row);
```

To something along the lines of:

```
$style = ($level == 0) ?  $this->styles['category'] : $this->styles['subcategory'];
$targetCoords = Cell::NUMBER . $row;
if($style->getActiveCell() != $targetCoords) {
    $sheet->duplicateStyle($style, $targetCoords);
}
```

Comment: Can I ask whether you tested the changes, did it really work?

Comment: Yes I did - in fact my post contains the exact case I was testing; also note that the pull request contains more changes than just the one in the PHPExcel_Style_Fill;

Comment: Just to clarify, I was able to reproduce your issue and workaround it by not duplicating styles from A1 to A1; also I developed a pull request so it is possible to perform such duplication after they merge it

Comment: Alright, I will test it out. Also my bounty is ending soon and your solution seems legit, so most probably you will get it.

Comment: Of course, when I get to test the stuff, I will accept the answer. And for now you can enjoy your bounty :P

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the specifics of the library...

How about changing this:

```
public function getHashCode() { //class PHPExcel_Style_Fill
    if ($this->_isSupervisor) {
```

To this:

```
public function getHashCode() { //class PHPExcel_Style_Fill
    if ($this->_isSupervisor && ( $this != $this->getSharedComponent() ) ) {
```

If the hash code logic after the `if` statement does not apply to `_isSupervisor`, then add another logic statement and return a fixed value, like this:

```
public function getHashCode() { //class PHPExcel_Style_Fill
    if ($this->_isSupervisor) { 
        if ( $this == $this->getSharedComponent() )
            return md5(0);
```

Comment: That could be a good idea, I tried it as well, but there is another recursive loop for some reason. `+1` though for the try. If fact that could work if we change a lot of code like that :D

Comment: If that's the case, it sounds like `_isSupervisor` is meant to be mutually exclusive with `$this == $this->getSharedComponent()`.  That might be a good place to look - what is this relationship, and should it be allowed to refer to itself?  Perhaps the mistake in the code is getting it to that place.  Good luck.