# Inserting multiple rows at once. How can this be shortened?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have to insert a few rows at once and every row gets the same value. Is there a way to shorten that query?

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('
    INSERT INTO `tablename`
    (`value`) VALUES (?), (?), (?), (?), (?)
');
$stmt->execute(array($value, $value, $value, $value, $value));
```

Comment: Have you tried executing this query?

Comment: Do you mean row (then see my answer below) or field? If the latter probably no.

Comment: That's what a fully qualified `INSERT` query looks like. Are you arguing that the SQL standard should be changed?

Comment: @Paddyd Yes, the query works fine.

Comment: @tadman No, no, that's not my intention. The question is more like: "*Can I re-use a value multiple times in a prepared statement*". Hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: Have you tried named placeholders? `VALUES (:value),(:value),(:value)` and then `execute(array('value' => 'x'))`?

Comment: @tadman Yeah, this was my first guess. And as expected it results in an `Invalid parameter number` exception.

Comment: It was worth a shot. Some other placeholder systems support recycling them that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$count = 5;
$value = 'HELLO';
$stmt = $db->prepare('
    INSERT INTO `tablename`
    (`value`) VALUES ' . implode(', ', array_fill(0, $count, '(?)')) );
$stmt->execute(array_fill(0, $count, $value));
```

Though I'm not sure I see much value in filling n rows of a table with identical values

Comment: Shorter and more flexible at the expense of maintainability. But shorter.

Comment: +1 I think I'll go with this, as it's more readable and even better maintainable then having lots of `(?)`. :) Thanks.

Comment: @MarkBaker I know this is not the most appropriate way to ask and so on, but could you please take a look at my question related to `PHPExcel`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18742595/phpexcel-style-fill-infinite-recursion  I would be really grateful if you could help, though you do not have to answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you can put the values in another table, you can repeatedly `INSERT` these:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE _values (v VARCHAR(255));
INSERT INTO _values ("x","x","x");

/* Repeat as necessary */
INSERT INTO tablename (`value`) SELECT v FROM _values;
```

Comment: +1 This looks very interesting and is probbaly very fast when inserting lots of lots of rows? I'll keep that in mind, for later. Sorry that I can only accept one answer. Still many thanks for sharing this and for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if below works.
But at least it gives you the syntax for several insertions at once.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('
INSERT INTO example
  (example_id, name, value, other_value)
VALUES
  (?, ?, ?, ?),
  (?, ?, ?, ?),
  (?, ?, ?, ?),
  (?, ?, ?, ?);
');
$stmt->execute(
    array(
        $value, $value, $value, $value, $value, 
        $value, $value, $value, $value, $value, 
        $value, $value, $value, $value, $value, 
        $value, $value, $value, $value, $value
));
```

Comment: This answer is not exactly answering anything. This is longer.

Comment: This isn't really shorter, isn't it? ;) And I only need to set one value per row. But it gets very long when inserting 10 or even more rows.

Comment: You can create the array with a function.  Then you can create the SQL with a function too. That would make your code short and readable.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you're using prepared statements, why not call execute() on a loop?:

```
$rowsToInsert = 5;

$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO `tablename` (`value`) VALUES (?)');
for($i = 0; $i < $rowsToInsert; $i++) {
    $stmt->execute(array($value));
}
```

It's certainly much easier to control programmatically than a single query multi-row insert.

Comment: This is also a *lot* slower since each `INSERT` is a transaction and will have MVCC and indexing overhead.

Comment: If performance is an issue, PDO's beginTransaction() and commit() could be used :/

Comment: There's still overhead for each statement. A mass-insert will win nearly every time, *especially* if there's a large number of rows being inserted.